# Nextflow - Process has already been used

Tags: nextflow

I am trying to write a nextflow script below:

```
/*
 * pipeline input parameters
 */
params.reads = "/path/to/fq/files/"
params.guide_library = "/path/to/guidelibrary/"
params.outdir = "results"

log.info """\
    DUAL GUIDE CRISPR QC - N F   P I P E L I N E
    ===================================
    guide library: ${params.guide_library}
reads        : ${params.reads}
    outdir       : ${params.outdir}
    """
    .stripIndent(true)

/*
 * define the `index` process that creates a binary index
 * given the transcriptome file
 */


process READCOUNT {
    input:
    path guide_library
    tuple val(sample_name) path(reads)

    output:
    path "$sample_name"

    script:
    """
    exactcounts.py -inputlibrary $guide_library -read1 ${reads[0]} -read2 ${reads[1]} -prefix $sample_name
    """
}

workflow {
    Channel
        .fromFilePairs(params.reads, checkIfExists: true)
        .set { read_pairs_ch }
   count_ch = READCOUNT(params.guide_library,read_pairs_ch)
    
}
```

But am getting the following error:

```
Process 'READCOUNT' has been already used -- If you need to reuse the same component, include it with a different name or include it in a different workflow context
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe adding a comma after `val(sample_name)` on line `tuple val(sample_name) path(reads)` will solve the issue.

EDIT: Also documented here: https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/discussions/2714